# "'precise' is no longer under development"

Tags: apport

Today when trying to use some keyboard shortcuts to navigate (mainly Alt + Tab, I'm not really sure which combination) I managed to crash Compiz. Then, in the middle of the crash report, Apport shows me this:

[image]

I really don't know what to do ;) I can't seem to reproduce the problem. What should I do to help fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are still using a beta precise release, can you let us know if your system is fully updated?

Comment: That window is one usually seen when running a pre-release (alpha or beta) version.  Such versions are meant for testing and are not finished products, although the later versions can actually be quite good.  Do you know if your computer was upgraded to the final release product, or could it still be running a pre-release version?

Comment: I'm not running beta. This installation is from the release CD. It's quite up to date too, I just updated a few days ago. Update Manager says there is nothing new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should choose `() Continue. I don't need technical support` at that screen, based on what you're saying in the question. You experienced a crash, but aren't getting it consistently, and can't force it to happen. But you want to file the bug report, so that it is known and tracked.

Comment: I did choose that, but I'm not sure how that helps this funny little problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should also file a bug against apport presenting this dialog to you then. You can run "ubuntu-bug apport" to do so. :)

Comment: Thanks, [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1020140) submitted. Let's wait to see what happens.

Comment: Once I do this, I never get a bug ID or URL.  So how is it possible to subscribe to it if I don't know where it is?

Comment: @Colan: I see Colan Schwartz in the list for "Notified of all changes". That's you right? I think it means you are subscribed.

Comment: Yes, but I did that manually.  When apport creates a new bug with a random crash file, how would I know where it ends up once it's uploaded?  Nothing is ever reported back.  Right now, I have to search through the crash file, find the title, and then search for it on Launchpad.  But this doesn't even work as my bugs don't show up there.

Comment: @Colan If your bug is a duplicate, it should show you the bug it is a duplicate of, when filing a bug. Or if you file the bug anyway, instead of just adding yourself to the existing bug, it will get marked as a duplicate after the crash is rescanned, and you are automatically subscribed to any bug that your bug is marked a duplicate of. You should get an e-mail about the bug being marked a duplicate, which will have both the new bug url, and your original, somewhere in it.

Comment: I found the problem!  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie for details.