# How to make apport always open a bug report page?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport, whoopsie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)

Since I updated to 12.04 apport sends crash reports to the server silently without opening a bug report page on launchpad while I'd like to track this reports statuses. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works in ubuntu 12.04 (final release) to edit `/etc/apport/crashdb.conf` and add `'Crash'` to the `'problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package', 'Crash']`

Some references

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/994921
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/993450/comments/13
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/997283

Comment: could this be the answer to my query https://askubuntu.com/questions/533203/can-i-follow-progress-on-autosubmitted-bugs and if so does it still work in 14.04 onwards? (it looks like it is deliberately not an apport feature?)

Comment: trying it out on 14.04 - now just waiting for a crash...