# /var/crash/ - should I send it?

Tags: crash, bug-reporting

I randomly receive a message from crash reporter roughly once a week. What should I do with it? I feel it is a non-essential bug and my report will simply pollute the bug tracking system. I can delete the report, but I don't want to delete information if it is valuable.

What is the rule of thumb for this?

Comment: For the kernel, at least, they log bugs/crashes statistically because they get so many crash reports, such that if there's a single instance of a unique crash, they may not bother to fix it, but if there are two crashes mostly equivalent in severity, one with 23456 instances, and one with 111, they're going to work on the more widely prevalent crash first.  In that scenario, you could consider your crash a democratic vote for getting the bug fixed.
http://www.kerneloops.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send it. The bug tracker is rather good at cleaning itself from dupes and incomplete bugs (or the maintainer of that bug is).

There is a very high chance it will get rejected as it will only accept crash report  for 1 problem. (I hope) you will get added to the "I am affected too" if you have a launchpad account connected. Otherwise: log into your launchpad account and do that yourself. That way you did your (albeit small) part in helping.

If it does go through it does need attention and others could expand on this error.

Related:

- [What happens after `ubuntu-bug` has done its thing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312261/what-happens-after-ubuntu-bug-has-done-its-thing)