# Would installing debugging symbols help for reporting bugs?

Tags: debugging, apport

I'm running a beta version of Ubuntu (12.10) and I've been reporting crashes through apport's automated system. I've glanced at the stacktraces for a couple of the issues and noticed a lot of what look like hex addresses and these:

```
No symbol table info available.
```

I was wondering if installing the debugging symbols packages from synaptic would provide better information to package maintainers when I report bugs. In other words, would the stacktrace be more useful if I installed those packages? If so, would installing those packages make any (noticeable) performances differences (will my computer run slower)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)