# Can I get further details on "Application has crashed" message

Tags: kubuntu, windows-xp

More often than not, on booting to Kubuntu 12.04.01, I get a pop-up message "An application has crashed, now or in the past". I dismiss the message and everything seems fine. Occasionally when booting recently to Windows XP as administrator (though not as regular user) I have had an equally non-informative message "Your system has recovered from a serious error".

Should I be worried; if so, how do I find out which application and fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details of recent application crashes are stored in the file `/var/log/apport.log`.

That should give you information on what application has crashed recently.

After that, I would recommend reading [How can I track a bug that caused a crash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)

I would also search [Launchpad](http://www.launchpad.net) for the application that you are seeing crash to determine if this may be a known bug.

Comment: Thanks maggottbrain, the file `apport.log.1` (which i will gladly share with anyone who's interested) refers to a problem with Nepomuk. There are also several `apport.log.gz` files, most though not all of whicn refer to the same problem. This seems to suggest that the problem is unconnected with my XP installation. Launchpad suggests that whoever is fixing Nepomuk bugs has enough on their plate, so I am inclined not to take further action, as the problem doesn't seem to cause me any problem. I have read the other sites and partly understand. Should I do anything more?

Comment: @WGCMan While it's not going to solve your problem, I would head over to launchpad and register that the bug affects you.