# Where do "internal error" error reports go?

Tags: apport

Every so often Ubuntu detects an internal error that it reports with a dialog box that looks something like this:

[image: Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error]

If I "Send an error report to help fix this problem" (via the checkbox), where do the error reports go?  I imagine this gets entered into a bug tracker somewhere, but which one?  Can I "watch" this bug, to get notification when it is fixed?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie

Comment: Yeah, or at least the accepted answer there contains the answer to this along with other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

All the errors from apport (which is the one reporting that the error occurred), will be stored in the `/var/crash` directory with the name of the process, PID, and other relevant information of the crash. When you send them using the tickbox, they are sent to [Lauchpad](http://launchpad.net) (pre-release) or [Ubuntu Error Tracker](https://errors.ubuntu.com/). This can be seen in the wiki page:

> If you choose to *send an error report*, the alert should disappear immediately. Data should be collected (if it hasn’t been already), and reports should be sent in the background, with no progress or success/failure feedback. If you are not connected to the Internet at the time, reports should be queued. Any queued reports should be sent when you next agree to send an error report while online.