# Where do I look to see if my sent crash reports is being tracked?

Tags: network-manager, apport, whoopsie

Recently I've been having an issue with NetworkManager crashing on boot or on resume from suspend. I enabled apport specifically, so I can report and track this issue.

When the problem occurs I get the *"A system problem has been detected"* dialog and follow through with reporting it. After the last dialog, nothing else pops up (I do see network activity which is presumably the crash report being uploaded).

I think understand that "system errors" (i.e., where you get the "System problem..." error message, aka "whoopsies"?) are handled by [ErrorTracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker) which is based on/uses apport - is that right?

Finally, getting to the point: I'd like to see my uploaded error report and the bug it is attached to (or enter the details to create a new bug). I did follow the link in Security and Privacy control (described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker#Accessing_previous_reports)), which looks like this:

[image]

The date is a clickable link, but it just brings me to a page with a graph of error reports with an error:

```
Sorry, you are not a member of a group that is allowed to see the data from error reports. Please fill out this form to request access.
```

There is no form on the page. I don't want access to see arbitrary error reports. I only want to see where my error report went and to see if it is attached to a bug, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since many automated bug reports are identical, only the first actually opens a bug report. The duplicates merely increment the data on the Error Tracker so we can tell which bugs occur more frequently.

Comment: @user53 - thanks! The question remains thought - how can I find the bug to which my report is associated, regardless of whether it is the first report or not? Without that info I can't follow the big, post additional details and I certainly can't roll up my sleeves and try to fix it.

Comment: You probably cannot. Most automatically-reported bugt start out as 'Private' to protect any reporter data included in the report. Often, a Triager or Developer will -after checking- change the bug to Public. Then you can see it on launchpad.net. 'Often' does not mean 'Always'. The easy way to find your bug, if Public, is to search for the error string - it's in the /var/crash file that whoopsie uploaded.

Comment: @user53 - fair enough. If the bug is already public, shouldn't I expect to be able to see it? Basically I'm stuck. As a competent developer I can provide value in terms of diagnosis and debugging, but if I can't even find the associated bug report I can't take the first step...

Comment: If you have the skills to triage the bug, or even to patch it, then pop into IRC #ubuntu-bugs and talk to one of one of the mentors there. "Hi, I think I can help with LP#xxxxxx, but it seems to be private."

Comment: [Did you look at `/var/crash`](https://askubuntu.com/a/461769/349837)? As you [saw](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker#Accessing_previous_reports) the patth is "apport -> whoopsie -> daisy.ubuntu.com -> errors.ubuntu.com". You are searching for apport's crash reports, no "whoopsies".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do "internal error" error reports go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237261/where-do-internal-error-error-reports-go)