# Get status of crash report

Tags: crash, bug-reporting, 20.10

I reported a crash on ubuntu 20.10, and after it was uploaded I noticed that in the `/var/crash/` directory a file named `<crash_name>.uploaded` exists which contains some sort of UUID. Can I use this UUID to follow the status of the crash report? Or, is there any way to check the status of my crash report?

As far as I read, the uploaded crashes are private and are only visible to Ubuntu bug control members, which then check if the upload contains any sensitive data and if so removes them before making them public? Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/q/900191/158442, but it's only answered in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The present crash-reporting system is simply not designed to connect you with your resulting bug report. Sorry.

Ubuntu's automated crash reporting is highly successful *from the engineer's point of view*: Lots of crash-related bugs get found and fixed this way. The report numbers guide bug-fixing priorities. It's a successful quality improvement system that benefits the entire user base.