# Is there anyway we can troubleshoot internal error with available information?

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting, apport, whoopsie

I've been using Ubuntu for more than a year now. Mostly for school assignments, and I don't use dual-boot. So I guess I quite enjoy it and I don't think I'd ever go back to my old OS.
This is about internal errors, I genuinely want to know if there's anyway I can troubleshoot this. I can say, I always get "**internal error report**" whenever I turn my machine on and I'd always report them, at least when I have internet connection but again I'm not blessed with 24/7 internet connection. But when I do, I always report them and check for any update as well. Just today I got this :

[image]

The left one, apparently my Java installation is causing crash, and in the error it's also written :

```
Unreportable reason
This package does not seem to be installed correctly
```

So I tried to fix my installation by running :

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

And it says it's already the newest version, I don't know where to go from there. Error on the right one, I don't know what it's about. I tried to looked for this issue and I came across these 2 questions :
 1. [Where do “internal error” error reports go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237261/where-do-internal-error-error-reports-go)
 2. [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)

But both are about error reporting (Ubuntu Error Tracking), not troubleshooting. So, I went to check my error reports and I got this :

[image]

So yes, my errors were submitted but I still encounter internal errors when I start my machine. Meanwhile waiting for any software update, is there anything we can do to troubleshoot this ourselves ? Because clearly even with update I still get these errors. Guess the updates are general ? Not specific for some reported error ? Some enlightenment or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: The implied question you seem to be asking is "is somebody working on these errors?" Maybe, depends upon the severity of the error, the type of problem, and how many others report a similar problem. Take a look in your /var/crash for details about each error - most of the troubleshooting information you need is in there.

Comment: @user535733 No, actually it wasn't. Of course I'd be glad if anyone will fix my errors but as I said I want to learn how to troubleshoot this (if possible). Like, should I re-install package when some specific error happens ? What can I do from information shown on the error report, instead of just waiting ? Something like that. Anyway, I'll be checking that page you said, thanks.