# Does my ubuntu 12.10 sends error reports?

Tags: 12.10, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)

I have question does my ubuntu 12.10 sends error reports ??

I often encounter this massage

[image]

in ubuntu 12.10 beta after I would press continue it would open up launchpad webpage in the webbrowser and i had to fill some forms but now when I press continiue, system does not open launchpad web page anymore
so is it something wrong with my system or did canonical changed the error handling ??

thank you for your time

Comment: The new behavior is [explained here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie/149455#149455) (I recommend we close this as a duplicate of that question).