# Where is my bug report sent?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, apport

How can I track my bug status after clicking "Continue" to "Send an error report to fix this problem"?

[image]

I have reported the bug a while ago and so far no fix. **Has the bug been even reported to Launchpad?** I read somewhere that the bug is only stored locally after clicking "Continue", unless the user reports it manually somehow.

I find the problem quite serious, **Xorg crashes at random time without any known connection to any action** I perform and sends me back to login screen. The report is similar to this and /var/log/syslog contains some CRITICAL red lines.

[image]

Note it is fully updated Ubuntu 15.10 with latest updates (excluding wily-proposed) running on an integrated Intel GPU (i5-2450M) with the default open-source drivers!

P.S.: I know of the [wikies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash), but I want to examine a REPORTED problem, or find WHERE has Ubuntu reported it (to Launchpad?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)

Comment: @muru The answer is rather old. Are you sure it considers Ubuntu 15.10? There is no explicit mention of that in the page.

Comment: unless something changes, people generally don't go around editing their posts each time a new version  is released.

Comment: The message shown here seems that you've sent an **error report**, which does not always create a bug.  Very rarely, does "Send Error Report" trigger a bug being created, as errors get reported to errors.ubuntu.com (of which only certain people can see the data incorporated in the error reports)